# Is there a way to check if chat session is 'on' for C# Google Gemini?

Tags: c#, google-gemini

Every time the button is pressed a new session is started and previous chat is forgotten.
How to solve this problem?

Below is the code used when button is clicked(using my own api):

```
async private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Gemini_API_Key", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
var modaal = new GenerativeModel(apiKey);
var chate = modaal.StartChat(new StartChatParams());
var resolt = await chate.SendMessageAsync("Write poetry");
Console.WriteLine(resolt);
}
```

If I try to jump a step ahead using loop or goto then I get error which says: use of unassigned local variable 'chate'.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have it so every time you press a button it is creating a new model and, more significantly, starting the chat with an empty history.

You may wish to make both the `modaal` and `chate` variables global (or at least outside the scope of the button handler) and create them when the application starts. Then pressing the button should send the message and handle the reply.

I'm not fully sure about the library that you're using, but it may store the history as long as you don't create a new session.